# Preserving IDs when using gCentroid to find centroids of multiple polygons in R

Tags: r, sp, centroids, rgeos, terra

This seems like it should be simple. I have multiple polygons contained in one shapefile, and I am using the `gCentroid()` function from rgeos to create a bunch of centroid points. The function has an `id` argument which should return the parent geometry Ids if left unspecified, but this is either not working or I'm looking in the wrong spot or I misunderstood the argument.

Simple example:

```
library(terra)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)

v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
v <- as(v, "Spatial")

#Clearly there are IDs here (albeit not unique) 
v@data[["ID_1"]]
```

so when I go on to create centroids

```
cents <- gCentroid(v, byid = TRUE)
```

I don't see any associated "ID_1" slot. The issue is I will eventually be using these centroids to derive values from a raster, and will need the IDs to distinguish which polygon the values originate from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the functions help is specifically states:

> Returns a SpatialPoints object of the centroid(s) for spgeom

So, it is not returning a SpatialPointsDataFrame thus, no @data slot. The results remain ordered to the parent polygons so, if you want an ID field, rownames or attributes just pull them from the @data slot from the polygons. The function does not search for an ID field in the @data data.frame. If it is associating anything it would be the rownames.

```
library(terra)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)

v <- as(vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")), "Spatial")
  row.names(v)
  rownames(v@data)

cents <- gCentroid(v, byid = TRUE)
  class(cents)
    row.names(cents)
```

Now, create a SpatialPointsDataFrame from the rownames, centroids and source @data slot

```
cents <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(cents, 
           data.frame(ID=row.names(cents), v@data))
  class(cents)
    head(cents@data)
```

Comment: Hey this worked great! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier with either `terra` or `sf`. For example

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
x <- centroids(v)
```